# how to pass proxy settings to chef/knife solo?

Tags: proxy, chef-infra, knife

when I run

```
knife solo prepare root@myserver
```

I get this output

```
Bootstrapping Chef...
Enter the password for root@myserver: 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6790  100  6790    0     0  10255      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10287
Downloading Chef 11.8.0 for ubuntu...
```

and it hangs....

I suspect proxy server troubles.

Is there a way to pass in proxy server environment variables with the proxy information?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proxy error. During the bootstrap, Chef is trying to execute a command as root, but that password has not been set. Even if you have Public-Key/Private-Key authentication enabled, your system may be configured to require a password to execute certain commands. You can specify the root user's password during the prepare state:

```
knife solo prepare -P XXX root@myserver
```

As instructed in the [documentation for knife-solo](http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/), you can also use `knife bootstrap` if you need more specific configuration options.

Comment: same result with -P <rootpw>  I'll look at knife bootstrap as you suggest

Comment: Nope, never did solve the issue.  I had to abandon chef, hope to return to attempt it again soon.